# Selenium selectWindow does not find window opened with openWindow

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

in Selenium IDE on FireFox 11, I use

```
openWindow | ${myURL} | receiverWindow
selectWindow | receiverWindow
```

and I get

```
[info] Executing: |selectWindow | receiverWindow | |
[debug] Command found, going to execute selectWindow
[debug] getWindowByName(receiverWindow)
[debug] getWindowNameByTitle(receiverWindow)
[error] Could not find window with title receiverWindow
```

With FireBug, I looked into the DOM of the sucessfully opened window and found a top-level entry: seleniumWindowName | "receiverWindow"

So, it looks like selenium seems to have stored the WindowID somehow but seems to look other places than where it was stored.

I also tried 
    selectWindow | "receiverWindow" (with quotes) but with no success.

What am I not getting right here?

Comment: Does it work in any other way? Could you please try with Firefox 10? There have been several problems with Firefox 11 as Selenium is not yet fully compatible with it.

Comment: Tried FF9 now, because I could not find a FF10 for Mac download. But it is the same there.
(Sorry for replying late, the mail escaped me)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the openWindowAndWait command instead of the openWindow command, does the subsequent selectWindow step succeed?

You may also need to specify ${receiverWindow} to reference the variable in the selectWindow step.